# Bootstrap scrolling navbar issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The website I'm working on: zarwanhashem.com

You can find my previous question (which includes my code) here: [Bootstrap one page website themev formatting problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575468/bootstrap-one-page-website-themev-formatting-problems)

The selected answer solved my issues but I have another problem because of the jQuery adjustment with the -50. Now the navbar incorrectly indicates the page I am on. i.e. The navbar is supposed to darken the section that you are currently in. So if you click "about" it will take you to the about page and darken the about link in the navbar. But the link BEFORE the page you are on is highlighted because the -50 makes the navbar think that it is on the previous section. You can easily try this to see what I mean.

How can I fix this? Thanks. The reason I didn't add this onto my old question is because the person stopped looking at it.

Also please keep your explanations simple/dumb them down a little for me. I know very basic HTML and CSS, and I don't know any Javascript.

scrolling js:

```
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top -50
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

js added at end of document as suggested by poster in previous question:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('div[class^="content-section"]').css('min-height', $(window).height());
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the .active class on the wrong element somehow. You need to put the .active class on the clicked element. You should handle the active state with js. This is my solution based on your HTML structure but I'm sure there are different solutions as well.

```
$(document).on('click', '.page-scroll', function(event) {
   var clicked = event.target; //get the clicked element
   if($(clicked).closest('ul').hasClass('dropdown-menu')){ //check if clicked element is inside dropdown
      $(clicked).closest('ul').parent().siblings().removeClass('active'); //remove active class from all
      $(clicked).closest('ul').parent().addClass('active'); add active class on clicked element parent - in your case <li> tag.
   }else{
      $(clicked).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
      $(clicked).parent().addClass('active');
   }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

**EDIT after you posted your code**

Try replacing your function with this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top -50
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

        if($($anchor).closest('ul').hasClass('dropdown-menu')){
           $($anchor).closest('ul').parent().siblings().removeClass('active'); 
           $($anchor).closest('ul').parent().addClass('active'); 
        }else{
           $($anchor).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
           $($anchor).parent().addClass('active');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: It fixes the highlighting issue, but it scrolls too far down (part of the page is cut off). And the scrolling animation is also gone now. Was I supposed to just add it onto the end of the scrolling js file? That's what I did.

Comment: I don't know your scrolling.js file but it doesn't sound right to put that code there. The code has nothing to do with scrolling. You should put it inside your main js file if you have one or on the bottom of your html code right before the ending `</body>` tag wrapped inside `<script></script>` tag. And not to break your scrolling code you should include your scrolling.js before your main.js (or before the code if you have no main.js).

Comment: I tried it and it went back to how it was originally (as if I never made any changes). I added the js I'm using in the first post.

Comment: The issue changed a little to a similar one. You can see it if you go the site. The first chunk of js I posted is the scrolling-nav file. The second piece is in script tags at the bottom of my index.html file and was suggested to fix the problem in my previous question (linked in my post). I replaced the scrolling-nav code with yours (but not the part that shrinks the navbar). The scrolling stops at the perfect spot, but the shading is still wonky.

Comment: It's the -50px on the scroll that is creating that mess for you. I don't see a reason why do you have those -50px. I would remove that and push your content down for 50px if you think that navbar will overlap your content. Once you remove the 50px it should work as you want it.

Comment: I tried it and you're right, it does fix the problem perfectly. But the -50 has to be there to fix the problem #2 I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575468/bootstrap-one-page-website-themev-formatting-problems    You can see the problem yourself if you go the site now (I took away the -50). How would I "push down" my content? I mentioned my problem with padding in the question I linked. Thanks.

Comment: push down your content by adding it a margin-top of 50px or more and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

here is a work around this problem.
just change the contents of your scrolling-nav.js to the following:

```
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
} else {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
}
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top -50
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo', function(){
        $('ul.navbar-nav li, ul.dropdown-menu li').removeClass('active');
        $($anchor).parent('li').addClass('active');
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}); 
});
```

Comment: I tried it and it works but it's kind of buggy. If you look at the site now you can see what I mean (I kept the adjustments). The fading comes and goes when using the about link, and the projects button itself isn't shaded, just the drop down component.

Comment: the only way to fix that is to modify the bootstrap.min.js and you can do that by using the bootstrap.js file instead and then you have to change the function for handling navbar highlighting although I don't recommend this solution while you will have trouble when updating your bootstrap later.